# Linux/c++ timing method to gaurentee execution every N seconds despite drift?

Tags: c++, linux, time, drift

I have a program that needs to execute every X seconds to write some output.  The program will do some intermittent polling and processing between each output.  So for example I may be outputing every 5 seconds, but I wake up to poll every .1 seconds until I hit the next 5 second mark.  The program in theory will run for months between restart, possible even longer.

I need the the execution at every X seconds to stay consistent to wall clock.  In other words I can't allow clock drift to cause me to drift away from the X second mark.  I don't need quite the same level of accuracy in the intermitent polling, but I would like to poll more often then a second so I need a structur that can represent sub-second percision.

I realize that by the very nature of running on an OS there wil be a certain inconsistency/latency in execution of any timer such that I can't gaurentee that I'll execute at *exactly* ever x seconds.  But that is fine so long at it stays a small normal distribution, what I don't want is for drift to allow the time to consistently get further and further off.

I would also prefer to try to minimize the CPU cost of the polling as much as possible, but that's a secondary concern.

What timing constructs are available for Linux that can best provide me this level of percision?  I'm trying to avoid including boost in the application due to hassles in distribution, but can use it if I have to.  So methods using the standard c++ libraries are prefered, but if Bosst can do it better I would like to know that as well.

Thank you.

-ps, I can't use c++11.  It's not an option so there is no way I can use any constructs from it.

Comment: What is your hardware platform?  Are you planning on running with a realtime kernel and realtime scheduling for your application?

Comment: Also, what "hassles in distribution" are you expecting from `boost`?  If you statically link to it, there is nothing to deploy/distribute.

Comment: I'm not running on realtime.  Regular redhawk linux (probably).  I don't need the percision of realtime, just to avoid drift.

Comment: the hassles with boosts are due to my employer not boost itself.  Good companies like hindering there employees with stupid restrictions after all!

Comment: @dsollen: The PC's internal clock will drift.  You'll need to consult a network time source with an atomic clock.

Comment: If you're worried about clock drift, don't use the clock.  You could use RDTSC if it's supported on your hardware (x86).  This counter monotonically increases with each CPU tick.  You can get the frequency of the CPU tick and find out how much it should "move" in one second, then poll against that counter periodically.

Comment: RSTSC is a no-go. Some CPUs have buggy implementations (multicore amd out of sync, for instance), others change frequency on power management modes. And it's hard to correlate tsc frequency precisely with walltime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[clock_gettime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/clock_gettime.html) and [clock_nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/clock_nanosleep.html) both operate on sub-second times, and use of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` should prevent any skew due to adjustments to system time (such as NTP or [adjtimex](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html)).  For example,

```
long delay_ns = 250000000;
struct timespec next;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &next);
while (1) {
    next.ts_nsec += delay_ns;
    next.ts_sec += ts_nsec / 1000000000;
    next.ts_nsec %= 1000000000;
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &next, NULL);
    /* do something after the wait */
}
```

In reality, you should check whether you've returned early due to a signal and whether you should skip an interval because too much time passed while you were sleeping.

Other methods of sleeping, such as [nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/nanosleep.html) and [select](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/select.html), only allow for specifying a time interval and use `CLOCK_REALTIME`, which is system time and may change.

Comment: According to this:  http://stuff.onse.fi/man?program=clock_gettime&section=3  CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is the one that needs to be used to avoid time changes due to NTP, etc.

Comment: This is great answer.  one follow up question though.  I may actually want to allow printing early in event of a leapsecond so the time appears continuous to those reading the file (still trying to get feedback on this at work).  I assume I could do this just by using a different constant to pass to the clock methods if I need to?

Answer (score 1):

If you need some exact timing without jitter or clock drift, make sure to have an external time source like a GPS, atom clock or radio time clock.
See for example the NTP integration documented in this [PDF](https://archive.fosdem.org/2012/schedule/event/697/129_ntp-fosdem.pdf). 
All NTP tricks work as well on Linux as on NanoBSD (which is in the PDF).

Answer (score 0):

I would record the time `t_0` when I started, then at any given time `t`, if `i = (t - t_0)/X` (integer division) is greater than the same quantity last time it executed, you execute again.

For example, suppose you are running every 5 seconds, if you started at time 23 you record `i = 0, t_0 = 23`. Then at time 27, `(27 - 23)/5 = 0`, so you don't yet execute. But next time around when it comes to time 28, `(28 - 23)/5 = 1`, which is greater than 0, so you execute.

This way you're not adding to a counter each tick which could have a huge drift, you're computing absolutely the time since the start so you know the exact times at which to execute.

Comment: Better yet, calculate the time until the next run, and use a sleep function (`select` or similar for portable sub-second `sleep`).  But the key is using the current time and 5 seconds after the last scheduled time, not 5 seconds from the current time.

Comment: Time only has a percesion of a second though doesn't it?  that would allow a variance of at least a second wouldn't it?  Also, would this mean a system call every time I did it or does C abstract away the need for system calls?

Comment: `select` give sub-second sleep.

Comment: And `gettimeofday` uses `struct timeval` which has microseconds just like what `select` takes.  `pselect`, on the other hand, takes `struct timespec` and nanoseconds.